# No material in the UV editor

Tags: materials, uv

I am trying to make skins for CSGO.
I have made a skin I like but I need to export it as a PNG file to then be converted to a file type that csgo understands. (VTF)
I am not able to see the models material in the UV editor, to then export it as a PNG.
My question, how do I see the material assigned to the object in the UV editor?
Please can someone help with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the right texture from the menu in order to see it in UV editor
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I might be missing something, but I am not using textures, but materials. It is just a solid colour that I am using.

Comment: Probably that's why you don't see it in UV editor. Because if it's solid color no need for UV map, it just covers all faces uniformly. UV map is needed when you use Texture image so you need to define how it should be align on faces. Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try and see if there is another way to do this.